# Jquery Slider, Spam clicking breaks my slider

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm looking for an answer or advice how to make my slider ignore any clicks on the arrows until the movement to either left or right arrows is complete.

I have a link here to show you exactly what is happening.

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/index/

and the Jquery code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var nav = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
    ul = $('#container .slider ul'),
    count = $('#container .slider ul li').length,
    width = count * 854;    

    $('#container .slider ul').width(width);

function slideRight() {
        ul.animate({
            left: '0'
        }, 1000);
    }

    function moveRight() {
        $('#container .slider ul li:first').insertBefore($('#container .slider ul li:last'));           
        ul.css("left", "-854px");
    }

    function slideLeft() {
        ul.animate({
            left: '-=854'
        }, 1000, function() {
            $('#container .slider ul li:first').appendTo(ul);           
            ul.css("left", "0");
        });
    }

    var autoSlide;

    autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
        slideLeft();
    }, 3000);

    $('#container .slider_container').mouseenter(function() {
        clearInterval(autoSlide);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
            slideLeft();
        }, 3000);
    });

    $('#slider-nav').show();

    $('#slider-nav .left_arrow').click(function(slideLeft){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#slider-nav .right_arrow').click(function() {
        moveRight();
        slideRight().delay(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't include "Thank you in advance... If anyone can point or fix this problem... Thanks" in your question. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to keep a variable that tells you whether or not you're currently sliding, and only to execute sliding functions if it's `false`. Then when a sliding function executes, set it to `true`, and tell the callback to set it to false. I've called the variable `sliding` in the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Flag to test on trigger
    var sliding = false;

    var nav = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
    ul = $('#container .slider ul'),
    count = $('#container .slider ul li').length,
    width = count * 854;    

    $('#container .slider ul').width(width);

function slideRight() {
        // Stop the function if we're already sliding
        if(sliding){
            return false;
        }

        // And now we're sliding
        sliding = true;

        ul.animate({
            left: '0'
        }, 1000, function(){
            // Slide over!
            sliding = false;
        });
    }

    function moveRight() {
        $('#container .slider ul li:first').insertBefore($('#container .slider ul li:last'));
        ul.css("left", "-854px");
    }

    function slideLeft() {
        // Stop the function if we're already sliding
        if(sliding){
            return false;
        }

        // And now we're sliding
        sliding = true;
        ul.animate({
            left: '-=854'
        }, 1000, function() {
            // Slide over!
            sliding = false;

            $('#container .slider ul li:first').appendTo(ul);
            ul.css("left", "0");
        });
    }

    var autoSlide;

    autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
        slideLeft();
    }, 3000);

    $('#container .slider_container').mouseenter(function() {
        clearInterval(autoSlide);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
            slideLeft();
        }, 3000);
    });

    $('#slider-nav').show();

    $('#slider-nav .left_arrow').click(function(slideLeft){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#slider-nav .right_arrow').click(function() {
        moveRight();
        slideRight().delay(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Legend is the only word to use here. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you, It doesn't seem to be working the when you click the left arrow anymore but sure I can figure that out

Comment: Well, I can't see your code in action, but from reading the script I noticed that that would be the case ;) — the last 2 functions determine what happens when the user clicks the left and right arrows: the right arrow triggers `moveRight` and `slideRight`, but the left arrow just triggers `event.stopPropagation`; you probably want to stop propagation on both and copy the code from the last function to the second last (replacing `Right` with `Left`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to check if an animation is running.

```
$('#slider-nav .right_arrow').click(function() {
    if(ul.is(":animated")) return;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is `slideRight()` is not returning anything...

```
function slideRight() {
    return ul.animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 1000);
}
```